# How to use pydbus to subscribe to services in systemd?

Tags: python, systemd, dbus

I'm trying to create a service with python that will monitor/subscribe to certain services in systemd (It will first need to pull information on all of them before subscribing). However I can't find a solution in dbus or pydbuses documentation to do that. I'm not sure what to import or what objects to use that allow something like that.

Using a CentOS 7.5 VM and pydbus 0.6.0.

For example if I were to do something like systemctl list-units | grep .service I could get all the services that I want to monitor, how can I monitor those services?

It looks like I could use the property of a service called ActiveState. I don't know how to use pydbus to connect to the systemd service to watch for ActiveState changes for each service.